# Setar texto no compartilhamento da API facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Tenho um script para partilhar conteúdo no Facebook está a funcionar bem só queria adicionar um texto que o sistema gera automático ao clicar no botão partilhar.

Exemplo:

[image]

Eu queria que onde diz `Diz algo sobre isto…` fosse um texto já predefinido.
É possível fazer isso ?

**Código utilizado**

```
 <script>
  FB.init({appId: "", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml:true });

  function postToFeed(description) {

    var obj = {
        method: "feed",
        message     : "Vê este comentário sobre '.$row_estabelecimento->titulo.' no @SabeOnde",
        link        : "'.$row_estabelecimento->link_site.'",
        picture     : "http://sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/capa/'.$row_estabelecimento_anexo->id_anexo.'.'.$row_estabelecimento_anexo->tipo.'",
        name        : "'.$row_estabelecimento->titulo.' | SabeOnde",
        description : "'.$row_posts->opiniao.'",
        display: "popup"
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response["post_id"];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode fazer isso usando sharer.php, mas você pode fazer algo semelhante, usando a **[API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui)** de diálogo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EXEMPLO:**

```
APP_ID = Facebook app Identifier    
"http://www.THEPAGE.com" = This would be my domain

    $('#share_button').bind('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var title = 'Title I want';
            var im_url = 'url_to_image';
            url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=APP_ID" + 
                        "&link=" + encodeURIComponent("http://www.THEPAGE.com")+ 
                        "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(title) + 
                        "&caption=" + encodeURIComponent('Shared from MY_PAGE') + 
                        "&description=" + encodeURIComponent('DESCRIPTION') + 
                        "&picture=" + encodeURIComponent("http://www.THEPAGE.com" +im_url) +
                        "&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com";
            window.open(url);
        });
```

**[Veja mais!](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog)**

*[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065179/facebook-sharer-title-and-summary-customization?answertab=active#tab-top)*

Comment: Obrigado vou fazer um teste e depois retorno o resultado

Comment: Não ajudou? Não resolveu?

Comment: tive a ver mas acho que o meu script esta igual eu vou colocar acima para ver

Comment: Assim com esse script tive a testar e acontece o mesmo do script que eu tinha